# Has anyone here ever used the word "professionality"? (Or is it even a word?)

Tags: nouns, is-it-a-word

I've heard the owner of our school say the word twice. Urban Dictionary even has a definition for it:

Professionality: The art of maintaining a professional appearance and attitude while projecting a tremendous amount of personality.
e.g.
Jason has the professionality to meet with clients and still be the life of the office. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=professionality

An academic from the University of Leeds has even used the term in a journal article: Evans, Linda (2008) Professionalism, professionality and the development of education professionals. British Journal of Educational Studies, 56 (1). pp. 20-38.

Yet, the word isn't entered in any of the major dictionaries.

What do you think about this word? Do you ever use it? Do many people use it?

Comment: Arguably, using such a namby-pamby nonce word could be said to reveal *lack* of professionalism.

Comment: It probably simply means 'the quality/act of being professional'.

Comment: It probably simply means 'the quality/act of pretending to be professional'.

Comment: Asking for peoples thoughts is way too broad! Asking if it's a word is opinion based - descriptionists would say yes of course, prescriptivists might not. You should [edit] this to strictly ask about usage, however you should also edit it to show your research - have you looked at NGrams etc?

Comment: Slang, and uncommon slang at that. As you should expect, having found it in The Urban Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's an unconscious response to a blanket negative attitude to '-isms', where 'professionality' would seem preferable to 'professionalism'.
Compare with 'dualism/duality'; 'mentalism/mentality', etc, where the '-ism' seems to be more substantial; the '-ality' more qualitative.

Answer (score 2):

While looking for any reason to require the addition of "ality" at the end of a perfectly good noun, I came across a paper titled "A Regression Model of Adjective-Noun Compositionality in Distribution Semantics." 
Even the spell check red-lined "Compositionality." To me, "professionalism" is more useful and less silly sounding than "professionality," which might be construed as a hyped-up word with no difference in meaning. Educators often are victims of "super-speak," using words that sound "educated" amongst themselves, but just sound like gobbledygook to the rest of us.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary has *professionality* first appearing in 1861.

Comment: ..with the meaning *professionalism*. Apparently Urban Dictionary (and Linda Evans of the University of Leeds) disagree.

Comment: OED also point out that *professionalism* came "slightly earlier", but what I find telling is that the definition for professionality is *Professional quality or character; professionalism* (i.e. - the less common form is defined using the more common form). The one for professionalism starts with much the same words *(Professional quality, character, or conduct)*, but even though the definition is much longer, it doesn't mention the other word at all.

Answer (score -1):

Singular unit of professionalism- knowledge, skills and procedures that an individual uses in their approach to a profession- ideologically, intellectually and attitudinally driven. Distinct from professionalism which refers to status related elements of a professional's work.

Comment: This looks like a dictionary definition. Answers here must reference any quotes they make.